# How does multilevel feedback queue scheduling works?

Tags: operating-system, queue, scheduling

I've been reading Ritchie “Operating Systems: Incorporating UNIX and Windows” chapter 4.3 about scheduling. And I struggle to understand how this scheduling algorithm works, as my test sort of contradicts my tutors.

Here's an example question:
2 Multi-level Feedback Queues, 1 CPU

```
-Time quantum is 5ms for both queues
-At time t=0 process P1(8ms) arrives
-At time t=2 process P2(7ms) arrives
-At time t=6 process P3(10ms) arrives
```

What is the final state of the processes,
queues, and CPU at time t=7?

So from my understanding this should be the outcome.

```
 T0 => Q1(P1(8ms) Running), Q()
 T1 => Q1(), Q2(P1(3ms) Ready) *preemptively moved to Q2*
 T2 => Q1(P2(7ms) Running), Q2(P1(3ms) Ready)
 T3 => Q1(), Q2(P2(2ms) Ready, P1(3ms) Ready) *preemptively moved to Q2*
 T4 => Q1(), Q2(P2(2ms) Ready, P1(3ms) Running)
 T5 => Q1(), Q2(P2(2ms) Ready) *P1(3ms) executed for 3ms and terminated*
 T6 => Q1(P3(10ms), Ready), Q2(P2(2ms) Running)
 T7 => Q1(P3(10ms), Running), Q2() *P2(2ms) executed for 2ms and terminated*
```

Yet the answer to this question is the following:

At time t=7:

```
-P1 has been executed for 5ms and it is in the READY state of the 2nd queue
-P2 has been executed for 2ms and it is in the RUNNING state
-P3 has arrived and it is in the READY state of the 1st queue
```

I'm confused, and the videos online are not helpful at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are misunderstanding what `time=7` means. Your calculations indicate that you took it as: "What will the state of the system be after 7 **intervals** of time?"

What they are asking here is: "What will the state of the system be **7 milliseconds** after it started running?"

And the answer to that question is:

```
-P1 has been executed for 5ms and it is in the READY state of the 2nd queue
-P2 has been executed for 2ms and it is in the RUNNING state
-P3 has arrived and it is in the READY state of the 1st queue
```

*Explanation:* P1 arrives at time=0 (i.e. 0 milliseconds after the system started) so it enters the ready queue Q1 and immediately starts running on the processor. After 5 milliseconds it is preempted and moved to Q2 where it waits to run the remaining 3 ms. At this time (5 ms after the system started) P2 has already arrived and it is waiting in Q1. So, it starts running. At 6 ms P3 arrives at Q1. So, *at 7 ms after the system started*: P1 is waiting at Q2 with 3 ms left. P2 is still running with 5 ms left. And P3 is waiting at Q1.

Comment: Beautifully explained, just what I needed. Thank you very much!